# AdBlock blocks my non-advertising sidebar images

Tags: plugins, customization, wp-admin

The AdBlock add-on blocks my non-advertising images which are displayed in the sidebar of my WordPress site pages. Is there any way to stop blocking these images? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally AdBlock blocks common advertising image sizes like 300*250, 720*90, 125*125. Change the image size to uncommon size.

Some file names like  banners, adv are also blocked. Your image will be blocked even if directory name has words like banners, adv.

Comment: this sounds too stupid to be true, citation required

Comment: @MarkKaplun At least it works for me. I had the same problem. it was because I had the images in a `/banners/` directory. I change the banners directory to `/images/` and make the size as 300*260 instead of 300*250. Then adblocker did not block the ad. I don't know about others. But at least it works for me without any problem. That's why I answered for  this question.

Comment: This might be all true but might be related to something you have on your site, people generaly blocking ads on it or many other reasons. In general it doesn't make any sense to check for image size as it is easily changed with css. If that was the criteria evrybody would have been serving slighly bigger image and use css to fit into an ad format

Comment: @MarkKaplun Many Adblocks analyze even CSS also. So  change using CSS won't work in many situations.

Comment: @Ranuka. Finally, your approach is correct. The size of my images was 300x600. I changed it to 300x610 and now I can make them display again with AdBlock enabled. Thanks.

Comment: @ Michael, Dave Romsey, Mark Kaplun, toscho. I apologize for my misplaced question but I couldn't know what the problem really was. It could be possible to have to change a filename like `widget_sideads.php` in WordPress Theme. However, my problem solved with the above answer.

Comment: @Mark Kaplun Atleast do test someone's solution first, before criticizing. This solution worked for OP though

Comment: @Ranuka, the standard for a good answer is an explanation why it works, not just that it works. It is not enough that it works for you right now, people that read it should be able to estimate if it will work for them as well, and you don't give any source to support your claim.